# i cant upload my site , my database was faild and i cant connect

Tags: php

I have a web page in my local host and I want upload my site on my domain but I have an error :

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'mentalmi'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

My database :

```
> $db_host=" localhost "; $db_user="mentalmi_zahra ";
> $db_pass="zahra1377"; $db_name="mentalmi_resturant";
> $db_table="resturant";
```

Please help me

Comment: have you added mentalmi_zahra user to database?

Comment: yes i added  mentalmi_zahra to  my database

Comment: but your error says for user mentalmi not mentalmi_zahra

Comment: Is your database connection file single, or you have added username and password on all files in which you have connection with database?

Answer (score -1):

You need to update your config file (the file where you input data for DB connection). From the error I could see, that your script still try to use configs for your local database.